# Log4j em aplicação Tomcat na AWS Beanstalk

Tags: java, spring, amazon-aws, log4j, elastic-beanstalk

Tenho uma aplicação multi tenant desenvolvida em Java WEB (Spring) que utiliza o log4j para registrar os logs. Cada tenant grava seus arquivos de log numa pasta especifica, correspondente ao tenant do usuário logado. Para tanto utilizo a seguinte configuração:

```
log4j.appender.<tenant> =org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.<tenant>.File=/home/user/sistemas/admin/logs/<tenant>/log.log
log4j.appender.<tenant>.Append=true
log4j.appender.<tenant>.MaxFileSize=500KB
log4j.appender.<tenant>.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.<tenant>.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.<tenant>.layout.ConversionPattern=%-2d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm};%m%n
```

Vem funcionando a contento, contudo surgiu a necessidade de migrar o sistema para AWS Beanstalk. Andei pesquisando se esse esquema seria possível de implementar lá, porém me restou algumas dúvidas.

É possível **salvar arquivos de log e realizar a leitura** utilizando somente **log4j** na **AWS Beanstalk**, caso positivo qual caminho devo definir, peço orientação nesse aspecto. Se não for possível, de que maneira vocês costumam realizar esse tipo trabalho?

Desde já, agradeço.